# TFS 2017 Update 2 on upgraded SQL 2017 cannot upgrade to TFS 2018

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

We had upgraded our SQL 2014 to SQL 2017 a few months ago, after checking that everything was working 100% even after the upgrade, we removed the VM Checkpoint.

Now we are upgrading our servers to Server 2019 from 2012 R2 and we are unable to transfer the databases to the new server, actually backup and restore of the database works fine but its the TFS upgrade that's not working.

TFS 2017 we are using only seems to support upto SQL 2016, so its not able to recognize the databases on SQL 2017 so when we try to upgrade the TFS to 2018 it doesn't detect the existing Databases on the server.

If we try to backup the database from SQL Management Studio and then restore it on TFS 2018 it doesn't detect the databases either.
We cannot restore the SQL 2017 backup of the database to SQL 2016 (obviously) but we are also not able to use Generate Scripts to extract database to .sql file, as the file size is large and even if I split it using software we are still getting errors in restoring.

At this point what are our options?

Comment: Are you backing up all of the databases? i.e. the Administration database and the Collection database(s)? Or are you detaching the collection database and adding it to a new TFS server instance?

Comment: Have you tried backing up TFS databases from TFS Administration Console? It has an option to take a full backup (it generates some .xml files with configurations related to TFS that you're not gonna get when backing up from SSMS)  and you can restore the backup on the TFS 2018 on the new server. The restore should also be executed from TFS Administration Console.

Comment: @JamesReed Yes off course, backing up all tfs Databases using SSMS, we have 3, Default Collection, Configuration & our data is in Core.

Comment: @Ronaldo I did try that first but wasn't sure how to restore the databases back. but i am going to try that again from within the TFS Administration console. I'll do a fresh install and then go into scheduled backups and restore databases. then try to add the restored databases to collection? or should I create the new installation databases with the same name as the old one?

Comment: @Ronaldo So I am able restore a backup taken from TFS 2017 Admin Console on to TFS 2018 Admin Console, but when i go to attach collection and enter the SQL instance name it says there are no attachable databases found.

Comment: about the collections, I assume you're following these steps to [Move a project collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=tfs-2018). If I got it right, you're stuck on step 4.3 because nothing appears in the list, am I correct? If so, did you verify that the database for the collection is online on the new server and that the user TFS connects to it have enough privileges? I ask cause I'm not sure now if that backup you restored brought online all databases from the old server or just the ones needed for TFS to work.